# Como executar uma função após o contextMenu aparecer?

Tags: javascript, html

Fiz um método para remover uma classe da minha div quando o `contextMenu` é chamado:

```js
minhaDiv.oncontextmenu = function () {
    this.classList.remove("classe");
}
```

Como posso fazer pra essa classe aparecer de novo **logo depois** que o context menu aparece?

Comment: Não sei se é isso que você procura pois a pergunta não esta clara(talvez se a contextualizar melhore), mas isso resolve `minhaDiv.classList.add("classe")` ?

Comment: Opa augusto, é isso que quero, mas eu quero que isso seja executado **depois** que esse método é executado

Answer (score 0):

Vou deixar aqui como resolvi o problema, é uma gambiarra e provavelmente não é a solução ideal, mas funciona.

Primeiro peguei o elemento que ficava embaixo dessa div (A div estava tampando esse elemento). Vou chamá-lo de imagem aqui.

```js
imagem.onmouseover = function(){
    minhaDiv.classList.add("classe");
};
```

Esse evento só acontece depois que a div já é removida, ou seja, não vai acontecer se o context menu já não tiver sido chamado. Aí é só o usuário passar o mouse na `imagem` que a classe é readicionada.

Só foi possível resolver assim porque a tal classe continha as informações de tamanho da div, então a div basicamente sumia sem ela.

Comment: Eu atá tinha entendido algo após o comentário. Deu a entender que fosse um caso de utilização de [`microtask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide) chegei até criar um exemplo https://repl.it/repls/PotableZigzagPort . Mas depois que li com atenção essa resposta sinto muito mas não dá para entender nada, apareceu uma imagem que não estava na pergunta. Sou obrigado a negativar pergunta e resposta pois a pergunta não possui informação alguma sobre a real problemática e resposta trata de algo que está só no seu computador.

Comment: O que eu quero é simples.
Tem uma div no meu site. Quero que, ao dar um rightclick nela, a div seja excluida e apareça o contextMenu normal. Após o context menu aparecer, simplesmente colocar de volta a div

Comment: Talvez não consegui me expressar bem, mas, basicamente, é isso. Obrigado de qualquer forma :)

Comment: Na pergunta era sobre remover e recondicionar classes, agora virou remover e recondicionar divs, Apareceu um contexmenu que não estava na pergunta, a imagem da resposta. Eu perdi 1 hora da minha vida para uma pergunta mal feita que não para de se modificar.

Comment: Eu removi as classes, não as divs.

Comment: E o context menu estava sim na pergunta, só ler, lol